# How to use dplyr's pipe with aggregate

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df<-data.frame(gender = c('A', 'B', 'B','B','A'),q01 = c(1, 6, 3,8,5),q02 = c(5, 3, 6,5,2)) 
  gender q01 q02
1      A   1   5
2      B   6   3
3      B   3   6
4      B   8   5
5      A   5   2
```

I want to calculate `q01*2+q02` and then get the `mean` by `gender` group,the expected result as below:

```
A 9.5
B 16
```

I tried but failed:

```
 df %>% aggregate(c(q01,q02)~gender,mean(q01*2+q02))
```

> Error in mean(q01 * 2 + q02) : object 'q01' not found

```
df %>% group_by(gender) %>% mean(.$q01*2+.$q02)
[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
>       In mean.default(., .$q01 * 2 + .$q02) :
>         argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OP's code for `dplyr` + `aggregate`, the `data` is not specified along with using `c` i.e. concatenate  two columns together. Also,

```
aggregate(c(q01,q02)~gender,df, mean(q01*2+q02))
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = c(q01, q02) ~ gender, data =
>   df) :    variable lengths differ (found for 'gender')

Here,with `c(q01, q02)`, it is like concatenating `c(1:5, 6:10)` and now the length will be double as that of previous along with the fact that the `FUN` used will not get evaluated as it wouldn't find the 'q01' or 'q02'

Instead, we can `cbind` to create new column with the `formula` method of `aggregate` and then get the `mean`

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>%
     aggregate(cbind(q = q01 * 2 + q02) ~ gender, data = ., mean)
#  gender    q
#1      A  9.5
#2      B 16.0
```

NOTE: In `dplyr`, the data from the `lhs` of `%>%` can be specified with a `.`.

NOTE2: Here, we assume that the question is to understand how the `aggregate` can be made to work in the `%>%`.  If it is just to get the `mean`, the whole process can be done with `dplyr`

```
f1 <- function(x, y, val) mean(x * val + y)
df %>%
    group_by(gender) %>%
    summarise(q = f1(q01, q02, 2))
```

---

Or using `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(q = mean(q01  * 2 + q02)), .(gender)]
#   gender    q
#1:      A  9.5
#2:      B 16.0
```

---

Or using `base R` with `by`

```
stack(by(df[-1], df[1], FUN = function(x) mean(x[,1] * 2 + x[,2])))
```

Or with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(q = q01 * 2 + q02) ~ gender, df, mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to keep `dplyr` and base approaches separate. Each of them have their own way to handle data. With `dplyr` you can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   mutate(q = q01 * 2 + q02) %>%
   group_by(gender) %>%
   summarise(q = mean(q))

#  gender     q
#  <fct>  <dbl>
#1 A        9.5
#2 B       16
```

and using base R `aggregate`

```
aggregate(q~gender, transform(df, q = q01*2+q02), mean)
```

Comment: I just don't understand why cannot directly `mean(.$q01*2+.$q02)` after `group_by`?

Comment: @kittygirl yes, that would work too `df %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarise(q = mean(q01 * 2 + q02))`. Just added a separate step with `mutate` to make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Sticking with the same logicc:

```
  df %>% 
   do(aggregate(I(q01*2)+q02~gender,
             data=.,mean)) %>% 
   setNames(.,nm=c("gender","q"))
  gender    q
1      A  9.5
2      B 16.0
```

**NOTE**:
I do  note that `do`'s lifecycle is marked as questioning.